# Selenium-Java is opening two instances of Firefox

Tags: java, selenium

I'm just starting to learn selenium java.
I had this test code, its just basically open google.com page and get its title, and assert the title. my problem is every time I run the test, the Firefox gets called twice. I already search around about the possible issue, tried some of the fix. but nothing works for me.. tried changing "@BeforeTest" to "@BeforeClass" and to "@Before" still the same.

firefox version: 55.0.3

selenium version: 3.5.3

geckodriver : 0.19.0

here's my code:

```
public class ATest {
    public String baseURL = "http://google.com";
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setBaseURL() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseURL);
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyHomePageTitle() {
        setBaseURL();
        String expectedTitle = "Google";

        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't call `setBaseUrl` inside `verifyHomePageTitle`. Let the testing framework call the methods. The testing framework calls `setBaseURL`, then calls `verifyHomePageTitle`. Since you called `asBaseURL` inside your test method, it's being called twice (once by the framework, once by you).

Comment: The setBaseUrl method is called twice in this test, before the test and during the test. What happens when you remove @BeforeTest completely and run it again?

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BeforeTest executes before tests so You need to remove setBaseURL() from Your test. It will be run before it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Selenium with Java, only with Ruby. But my guess is that `@BeforeTest` directive makes *setBaseURL()* to be executed before each test. So here you have your first opened browser. Later when in your actual test what you do is you run *setBaseURL()* again, which opens second browser.

Remove *setBaseURL()* from *verifyHomePageTitle()*, or remove `@BeforeTest`

Comment: Thank you so much.. thats why.

Answer (score 0):

`get` method is called twice hence it loads page twice. Once in `@BeforeTest` and second in `@Test` by calling `setBaseURL`. Remove the `setBaseURL` from `@BeforeTest`, move the `get` method in actual `@Test` method and you should be fine

Here is what java doc says about `get` method

```
void    get(java.lang.String url)
Load a new web page in the current browser window.
```

> get
>
> void get(java.lang.String url)
>
> Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an HTTP GET operation, and the method will block until the load is complete. This will follow redirects issued either by the server or as a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. Should a meta-redirect "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout is over, since should the underlying page change whilst your test is executing the results of future calls against this interface will be against the freshly loaded page. Synonym for WebDriver.Navigation.to(String).
>
> Parameters: url - The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL

```
public class ATest {
    public String baseURL = "http://google.com";
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setBaseURL() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyHomePageTitle() {
        driver.get(baseURL);

        String expectedTitle = "Google";
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
    }
}
```

Links for reference

- Java Doc : http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get-java.lang.String-

Comment: np, if it has helped you solve problem then vote up :)